# How to make a snake game where each snake tile follows it's connected tile

Tags: javascript, data-structure, pico-8

I want to make a basic snake game. It has a head and a series of tails that occupy a tile in a grid. The first tail in the series is adjacent to the head. and each tail that comes after is adjacent to the previous tail. Head can move in four directions and the first tail moves to head's previous position, and each other tail moves to the previous position of the previous tail, as they follow each other.

How can I model this as data, and update it for movement.

I've tried this but that's a little doesn't work.

```
p = {
  x=0,
  y=0,
  tails={}
}

function init_tail(dx,dy)
   return {
      x=0,
      y=0,
      dx=dx,
      dy=dy
   }
end
-- Initialization
add(p.tails, init_tail(0,1))
add(p.tails, init_tail(0,1))
add(p.tails, init_tail(0,1))

local last = p
for tail in all(p.tails) do
   local tx = last.x + tail.dx
   local ty = last.y + tail.dy
   tail.x = tx
   tail.y = ty
   last = tail
end
-- Movement
local last = p
for tail in all(p.tails) do
   tail.dx = -last.dx
   tail.dy = -last.dy
   local tx = last.x + last.dx + tail.dx
   local ty = last.y + last.dy + tail.dy
   tail.x = tx
   tail.y = ty
   last = tail
end
```

This is what I have so far: [image: snake game]

Comment: Did you try looking at past Q&A in the [tag:snake] tag for some leads? This is a mechanic with lots of existing tutorials and sample implementations available online, so I doubt there's much new that we could tell you that hasn't already been said.

Comment: This example in the Lexaloffle BBS might have something you could use: https://www.lexaloffle.com/bbs/?pid=69789#p